# Проблема c кодировкой кириллицы Python 3 + bottle

Tags: python-3.x, кодировка, utf-8, python-3.5

Есть скрипт Python 3.5 использующий веб-фреймворк bottle.py. Через форму с textarea вводится русский текст и отправляется через POST на сервер. Нужно затем отобразить введенный текст. Выводятся кракозябры типа

ð°ð¿ð°ðμð°ðμð°_ñð;629V_Ble;ÑÐ¾Ð»Ð»Ð»Ð¾Ñ Ð´Ð»Ð¶Ð´Ð¾Ð»Ð´;Ð°Ð¿Ð°ÐµÐ°ÐµÐ°.

Я так понимаю какая то проблема в кодировке. Подскажит, где копать?
В начале скрипта стоит ## -*- coding: utf-8 -*-.

**Вот пример скрипта, который лежит рядом с bottle.py:**

```
## -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from bottle import route, run, template, get, post, request

@route('/loggen')
def loggen():
    return template('loggen')

@post('/gen')
def gen():
    fios = request.forms.get('fios')

    return "<p>"+fios+".</p>"


if __name__=='__main__':
    run(debug=True, reloader=True)
```

**А это шаблон через который вводим текст**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Генератор логинов</title>
 </head>
 <body>

  <form action="gen" method="post">
  <p><h1>Генератор логинов</h1></p>
    <p><b>Список ФИО:</b></p>
    <p><textarea class="form-control" rows="15" cols="100" name="fios">       </textarea></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Создать логины"></p>
  </form>

 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ нашелся в доке Bottle
http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#introducing-forms

In Python 3 all strings are unicode, but HTTP is a byte-based wire protocol. The server has to decode the byte strings somehow before they are passed to the application. To be on the safe side, WSGI suggests ISO-8859-1 (aka latin1), a reversible single-byte codec that can be re-encoded with a different encoding later. Bottle does that for FormsDict.getunicode() and attribute access, but not for the dict-access methods. These return the unchanged values as provided by the server implementation, which is probably not what you want.